# any relation between blender scale and unity scale?

Tags: transforms, edit-mode, unity, .fbx

Hi I would like to know , how can i do for my 3D objects can able to keep their blender's dimention? when I export an .fbx  from blender to Unity. 
I am modeling some assets  (see my picture)

[image]

so I am trying to make an arcade machine , destopkt  and some stuff such as coffe cup ,etc... I prefer to modeling in "metric system" and the most similar to the real world .. ( I always start to model very high scale and then when I finished I use to scale the whole objects to the real life scale or similar at least.. for example 1,75 meters  for Z axes for the arcade cabinet)

well ... at finally when applied (rotation , location and scale in blender I am ready to export) ...but when I export my assets to Unity in (.fbx) as format...my scale is (100,100,100 in Unity I think it is ok! )...but my dimensions are very huge!!! ,
however when I set in Unity (1,1,1 to all axes here in unity) my assets take the real dimentions of blender ... ( I do not like to change the scale !! ) how ever...in unity I can put 1,1,1 and the assets match very well...

am I right to change the scale in unity? by default is 100,100,100...I just only want to keep my real and good dimention from my assets from blender to Unity...and not suffer issues from ray tracing from this engine for huge objects.

my conclution is if any kind of models want to keep his own dimention, change the scale to 1,1,1 in unity...but is it ok?

Comment: Are you sure you applied scale before exporting? Have you set any scene units in Blender under the *Properties Window > Scene > Units* ? Have you defined an export scale on the export dialog properties?

Comment: yes, I used to go to propeties windows and in the scene display I choose metrics units , after modeling process I applied the scale al ways (1000,1000,1000)  , then when I export I chose the format (.fbx) . There is a export dialog propeties which shows an option to scale in "1" factor ( if I chose it the export  will be 1,1,1 in unity...if I do not choose the scale option in the dialog box (weird symbol) the scale will be 100,100,100 (in unity) I do not know if I must to choose that weird symbol or just leave the option as default .

Comment: I found this thread in another post... I think this is the solution ???
 what do you think ??http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1200226/imported-models-from-blender-277-are-scaled-x100-i.html